# asp.net equivalent of simple php code

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am working on a jquery plugin which takes json data from the php page. Now i am trying to do the same thing in a asp.net web service. But i m finding hard to understand the php code. Also i cant host the php page in iis due to restrictions. Please help me to modify the code for asp.net webservice.

```
<?php

    $year = date('Y');
    $month = date('m');

    echo json_encode(array(

        array(
            'id' => 111,
            'title' => "Event1",
            'start' => "$year-$month-10",
            'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
        ),

        array(
            'id' => 222,
            'title' => "Event2",
            'start' => "$year-$month-20",
            'end' => "$year-$month-22",
            'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
        )

    ));

?>
```

Jquery code for reading...

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            eventSources: [

            // your event source
        {
        url: '/myfeed.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            custom_param1: 'something',
            custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        },
        color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
        textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
    }   
    ]
        });
    });
```

Comment: You dont need how coded in php. Just write your own code in asp.net that will give json output as you want.

Comment: Actually i need what is expected by that piece of code.. i mean how will the array look.

Comment: You can use `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` for JSON serialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a read of http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/ and http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/

The correct webservices should output JSON objects.

If you want a JSON serialiser then have a look at: http://json.codeplex.com/

Using @safarov's code, you should be able to call the serialise method to return it as a JSON string:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject)
```

Comment: Just to add, from everything I have read all the 3rd party JSON serializers are quicker in execution then 'System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer' hence I recommend investing other options to the inbuilt one.

Comment: Unless you're handling a huge volume of requests, the difference between the serializers is negligible. You might shave a fraction of a millisecond off each single round-trip by using a faster one, but that's premature optimization when most of your performance overhead is usually in saving and/or reading data.

Answer (score 2):

THis is the json code that will be output

```
[
 {
  "id": 111,
  "title": "Event1",
  "start": "<current year>-<current month>-10",
  "url": "http:\/\/yahoo.com\/"
 },
 {
  "id": 222,
  "title": "Event2",
  "start": "<current year>-<current month>-20",
  "end": "<current year>-<current month>-22",
  "url": "http:\/\/yahoo.com\/"
 }
]
```

Due to this write asp code

Comment: Thanks, I got it.... System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer is the key.